# Visual Studio Shortcu/Syntax for fast property assignment

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, properties

Say Suppose you have a class

```
public class Person

{

public int PesronId{get;set;}

public string FirstName{get;set;}

public string LastName{get;set;}

public string Gender{get;set;}

}
```

Now We create an object p1

```
Person p1 = new Person();
```

Next we have values from textboxes to be assigned to p1
eg.

```
p1.PersonId = textbox1.text;

p1.FirstName = textbox2.text; 

p1.LastName = textbox3.text;
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this in Visual Studio 2010, by which I will get something like this

```
p1.PersonId =

p1.FirstName = 

p1.LastName =
```

so that I dont have to manually type the properties for p1.

Or is then an alternate syntax that I can use.

Comment: same question here...when you've got to build these assignment blocks for each of 20 tables, and each table has between 20 and 50 columns....we're talking about a LOT of typing...it sure seems like something could fill this gap.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's simpler *syntax* for the code:

```
Person p1 = new Person
{
    PersonId = textbox1.Text,
    FirstName = textbox2.Text,
    LastName = textbox3.Text
};
```

This is [*object initializer*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) syntax, introduced in C# 3.

I think I'd misread the question though - it sounds like you're just interested in cutting down the *typing* required. There may be something which will do that, but personally I find IntelliSense is fine on its own. The readability of the code afterwards is much more important than the time spent typing, IMO.

You might also want to add a constructor to Person to take all the relevant property values - that would simplify things too, and with C# 4's named argument support, you can retain readability.

Comment: ReSharper has some IntelliSense extensions that further cut down on typing, but in general I agree with you; learn to use IS and CEPM (code elements per minute) goes way up.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll stick to IS

Answer (score 1):

You can use the new initialization functionality in C#:

```
Person p1 = new Person()
{
     PersonId = textbox1.text,
     FirstName = textbox2.text,
     LastName = textbox3.text
};
```